# How to use the summation symbol correctly

Tags: summation

I'm absolutely horrible at maths. I'm trying to write out mathematically that for every two minutes in a day a function executes, and this function results in saving `x KB of data and y KB of some other data` to a computer disk. Now I want to write out how much space it would take up in a day. So far this is what I got, assuming that `S= x KB of data per execution` and `K= y KB of data per execution`. I use 720 as it would execute that many times a day. Every 2 mins => 30 times an hour => 30 * 24 = 720

[image]

It looks ugly though and not right. Is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_i$ denote the amount of data $x$ stored in the $2i$th minute of the day and let $K_i$ denote the amount of data $y$ stored in the $2i$th minute of the day. Then, we have that the total data stored in a day is
$$S_0+K_0+\cdots+S_{720}+K_{720}=\sum^{720}_{i=0}\left(S_i+K_i\right)$$
So, yes, it's right.